# Alterar user agent

Tags: php, http, user-agent

preciso alterar o user agent no mobile. Tentei com php puro mas não deu certo, estou utilizando o Mobile Detect, até consigo detectar quando é mobile, mas não consigo alterar o user agent.

O exemplo que segui foi este

```
if(!$detect->isMobile()) {    
    $userAgent = 'BlackBerry7100i/4.1.0 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 VendorID/103';    
    $detect->setUserAgent($userAgent);    
    echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "<hr />\n";
}
```

O que está errado?

Answer (score 1):

O user-agent é o que o cliente informa. Se o cliente informar um user-agent diferente do que ele realmente é, o servidor não tem como saber.

Dito isso, o $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] é setado no momento que o servidor recebe a requisicao. Mesmo com a alteracao, a variavel já está definida (com o valor antigo).

Tente

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = 'BlackBerry7100i/4.1.0 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 VendorID/103';
```

Comment: Deu certo Victor, mas ele ainda não traz toda a versão desktop. O que eu deveria fazer? Gravar um cookie, uma sessão e recarregar a página? Preciso imitar a função "Requisitar site desktop" igual no Chrome pra celular.

$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36';